# Electron app hangs often

Tags: javascript, electron

we have built mac and windows desktop version of our app using electron framework, but it hangs and become unresponsive really often. Using chrome natively it does not happen. Is there any flags that needs to be added/removed when using electron framework, and what could be the difference? The biggest problem that I don't have knowledge how to debug these kind of problems, because logs does not return anything before hanging, and profiling becomes unresponsive too. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to update your electron install. Other than that what action is your app doing when it hangs?

Comment: It even don't have an install yet, I run it using "npm start" only. The action is unknown, because it is messenger software it does many things at once, so that what I would like to trace somehow which method makes app to hang, thanks.

Comment: See Julian's answer below. It might not solve your specific problem, but it will give you the best start at solving the problem.

Comment: By install I meant update the electron runtime. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the Chrome Developer Tools with

```
require('remote').getCurrentWindow().toggleDevTools()
```

From there you can profile it like a normal webapp, you can take a look there what takes much time. There are many good tutorials how to use these tools.

Comment: Yes I tried to use dev tools, but it hangs together with all the app, and profiling just freeze and you can't even click stop or check whats happened.

Comment: Maybe then it would be better to ask, is there any way to watch and profile an app in chrome with devtools and get the results even the whole window (including devtools) hangs? Maybe profiling info gathered to some file which can be viewed in disk after chrome was closed or something, thank you for your help.

Comment: Try to attach an external debugger (http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/debugging-main-process/).

Comment: External debugger only debugs main process I think, and app hangs in renderer thread.

Comment: If you want to debug chromium itself you can compile it with a debug flag or listen to system calls ... but all that stuff is very complex and i think it is not the renderer, because it works in the browser. It is easier to look what in your code causes the freeze (What happens before the freeze)